# Persisting Facebook page tab login

Tags: php, facebook, authentication

I am trying to make a pretty simple facebook page tab application. All I need is to tell if the user is a page admin or not using `$pageTabHelper->isAdmin()`.

It returns the correct value when a user opens the page tab for the first time, but whenever he follows an hyperlink in the app, the `$accessToken` changes to null and the user is not an admin anymore, even if he returns to the original "index.php" page.

Here is a test page that shows the issue.

```
<?php
require_once __DIR__ . '/../Application.php';

$app = new Application();

$facebook = $app->getFacebook();
$loginHelper = $facebook->getRedirectLoginHelper();

$pageTabHelper = $facebook->getPageTabHelper();

// Grab the signed request entity
$request = $pageTabHelper->getSignedRequest();

// Get the user ID if signed request exists
$user = $request ? $request->getUserId() : null;

if ( $user ) {
  try {

    // Get the access token
    $accessToken = $pageTabHelper->getAccessToken();
  } catch( Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e ) {

    // There was an error communicating with Graph
    echo $e->getMessage();
    exit;
  }
}

echo "<h1>isadmin</h1>";
echo var_dump($pageTabHelper->isAdmin());

echo '<a href="/index.php?test=test"> test link </a>';
?>
```

The application was added to the user's allowed apps using this piece of login code.

```
if (!isset($accessToken)) {
  function isSSL()
  {
    return (!empty($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] !== 'off') || $_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] == 443;
  }

  $callback = (isSSL() ? "https" : "http") . "://" . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . 'facebook_login.php';
  $loginUrl = $loginHelper->getLoginUrl($callback, ['public_profile']);

  echo '<a target="_blank" class="facebook_login" href="' . $loginUrl . '">Log in</a>';
}
```

I feel like I am misunderstanding some very basic thing about how Facebook authentication works. Why can't the user follow the "test link" hyperlink without breaking his authentication?

Must I make the whole app a single page and use ajax instead of hyperlinks and postbacks?

Comment: The `signed_request` parameter is POSTed to your app only on initial load into the iframe – so you should execute code that tries to get information from it only then (resp. after you checked that the parameter exists), and not on every page. You are likely just getting `null` in `$request` on your subsequent in-app pages, and then `$user` will be set to `null` as well by your code …

Comment: Alright, so I'll need to load all of the permission data into a session variable on the first page load. I expected some Facebook API call that would have persisted the signed request since I need to call session_start to even use the API...

Comment: @Cbroe: you should add that as the answer, that's what I was going to say too

Comment: @Cbroe : yes, just put that in an answer and I'll accept it for future reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `signed_request` parameter is POSTed to your app only on initial load into the iframe – so you should execute code that tries to get information from it only then (resp. after you checked that the parameter exists), and not on every page.

(You are likely just getting `null` in `$request` on your subsequent in-app pages, and then `$user` will be set to `null` as well by your code.)

Comment: I did just that, storing the "IsPageAdmin" and "IsLoggedIn" parameters I needed in the PHP session when $accessToken was set and retrieving the stored values when it isn't and it worked perfectly. It should be possible to do the same with the user's access token to use in the graph API.